# Group location points that have a cumulative value 2000

Tags: qgis, r, clustering

I have a set of 400 locations (points) joined to a table having population attributes.
I want to form groups of nearby locations such that the cumulative population is 2000, group can have maximum 15 locations.
Is there a way to do it using QGIS and/or R?